# Serverless framework AWS cross-account custom authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How to setup cross account custom authorizer with serverless framework? Custom authorizer configured with sls framework works fine if it is in the same AWS account as function that needs authorization.

What I have now is organization root account where authorizer function has been deployed. On the second account, which is organization member, I have a serverless service deployed with the endpoints that needs to be authorized from the root account.

Is it possible to configure something like this inside serverless.yml that will be deployed on the member account (111111111111 is root account number):

```
  hello:
    handler: api/hello.handler
    events:
     - http:
        path: hello
        method: get
        cors: true
        authorizer: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:111111111111:function:authorizer
```

I have tried this and received following error:

> An error occurred: AuthorizerApiGatewayAuthorizer - The policy of
>   Lambda function must explicitly authorize the method or custom
>   authorizer with a SourceArn condition for cross account integration
>   (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   BadRequestException;

... which makes sense according to the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-lambda-authorizer-cross-account-lambda-authorizer.html). These docs explains how to manually do it using API Gateway console which is exactly what I did  for now (authorizer in the root, authorizer in the member account - manually connected through API gateway, same as described in the docs).

I need a better solution as the number of services and organization member accounts is going to grow.

Is it possible to configure and make this work with serverless framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with a lot of the Serverless Framework, there's a plug-in for those times that CloudFormation hasn't yet offered an option:

https://github.com/rschick/serverless-plugin-lambda-account-access

The **custom authorizer's** `serverless.yml` should then include:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-lambda-account-access
provider:
  allowAccess:
    - 111111111111 # account id of invoking account
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This does not 100% resolves my issue because I would need to update permissions or in this case re-deploy root with updated provider section every time I add new account (re-deploy is something that I would like to avoid), but gives me a strong idea how to proceed and implement it for my use case. Once again, thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: No worries- I don't think you'll ever get away without doing _something_ every time you add a new account I fear.